# Custom motion estimation model for Kalman filter in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, motion-detection, kalman-filter

I have been trying to apply the `multiObjectTracking()` function from [this example](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html) to some videos of insect motion on a 2D surface.

In the linked example, a Kalman filter is used for estimating the motion of tracked objects if they are lost for a few frames due to foreground occlusion. The filter is set up using the `configureKalmanFilter()` method using the 'Constant Velocity' model for motion estimation. Alternatively it can be called with the 'Constant Acceleration' model.

My question is how would I set up a custom model for motion estimation in my Kalman filter?

The primary cause of lost tracks in my footage is when an animal stops for several frames then begins walking again, possibly in a different direction. Therefore i would like to implement a 'No Velocity' model (so to speak) that assumes the lost object has simply remained in its last known location until it is picked up again.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the [vision.KalmanFilter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.kalmanfilter-class.html) object directly, without using the `configureKalmanFilter` function. In that case, you can pass in a custom state transition matrix. However, since this is a regular Kalman filter (not extended or unscented), the state transition must be linear. So I am not sure what other motion model you can reasonably use, other than constant velocity or constant acceleration.